# Как автоматически добавить "логин" в "поле для ввода логина" на странице в элементе WebBrowser

Tags: веб-программирование, visual-basic

Как записать текст в определённый `TextBox`, который находится в загруженном окне элемента WebBrouser-а?
Например, я загружаю сайт в элементе `WebBrowser` и когда он загрузится, в поле для логина автоматически написать логин (любой *string*)

Логика думаю такая: нужно узнать определённое место (`TextBox`) на странице, где нужно вводить логин, потом ввести логин. Но как это реализовать? Приведите примерный код, пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [GetElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx#Y522), например:

```
If (WebBrowser1.Document IsNot Nothing) Then

    Dim SomeElem As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(SomeID)
    If (SomeElem IsNot Nothing) Then
        SomeElem.InnerText() = "Some"
    End If
End If
```